# Java ClassNotFoundException when reading object from a stream

Tags: java, serialization, objectinputstream

I am getting a ClassNotFoundException when reading an Object from an ObjectInputStream. The object that is being sent is subclassing "WorkUnit" which the reading code has a reference to. It would seem that the receiving end is complaining because it doesn't know about the specific implementation. Why would it care about that when I'm only referencing the object's superclass: "WorkUnit" on the side that is receiving?

Code to read from Stream:

```
private Object readObject() {
    Object object = null;
    try {
        object = objectIn.readObject();
    } catch (SocketException | EOFException e) {
        // Socket was forcedly closed. Probably means client was
        // disconnected
        System.out.println("[NetworkHandler] SOCKET CLOSED");
        shouldContinue = false;
        if (!isClient)
            server.clientDisconnected(clientID);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        // If shouldContinue is true, we haven't said that we want to close
        // the connection
        if (shouldContinue) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err
                    .println("[NetworkHandler] Error: Couldn't read object correctly");
        }
    }
    return object;
}
```

Work Unit Implementation:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import Application.WorkUnit;


public class WorkUnitImplementation extends WorkUnit<Integer, Integer> {

private static final int INPUT_LENGTH = 1000;

public WorkUnitImplementation() {
    super();

    setInputLength(INPUT_LENGTH);
}

@Override
public Integer doWork(Integer input) {
    wait(50);
    return (input % 2 == 1) ? input : null;
}

@Override
public List<Integer> inputFactory(int begin, int end) {
    List<Integer> result = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = begin; i < end; i++) {
        result.add(i);
    }
    return result;
}

private void wait(int time) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(time);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
}
```

Code to send Work Unit:

```
    public void uploadWorkUnit(WorkUnit workUnit) {
    try {
        objectOut.writeObject(new UploadWorkUnit(workUnit));
        objectOut.flush();
        System.out.println("[NetworkHandler] Uploaded workUnit");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Exception Trace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WorkUnitImplementation
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:622)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1593)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1750)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1888)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
at Networking.NetworkHandler.readObject(NetworkHandler.java:188)
at Networking.NetworkHandler.run(NetworkHandler.java:90)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

[NetworkHandler] Error: Couldn't read object correctly

Comment: Post your code. If you don't, then the answer is "your guess is as good as mine".

Comment: Please post your code, and the exception trace you receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It would seem that the receiving end is complaining because it doesn't know about the specific implementation. Why would it care about that when I'm only referencing the object's superclass: "WorkUnit" on the side that is receiving?

It's because the stream consists of the *implementation* class' fields.

From [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) javadoc:

> The default serialization mechanism for an object writes the class of the object, the class signature, and the values of all non-transient and non-static fields.

The deserialisation process reads the stream to discover the class that should be automagically reconstituted.  It tries to create a new instance of that class so that it can then populate it with the fields that are contained in the stream.

If the receiving end doesn't have the same class that was written, it won't work -- you'll get a `ClassNotFoundException`.

(That said, the class being serialised could use `writeReplace()`, but that's probably beyond the scope of this question).

Comment: On the sending side, I'm already reading the .java and compiling it. Do you think I could hack together a solution by sending the .java and compiling it on the receiving end?

Comment: Or, could I override the writeReplace() and return the super class?

Comment: @rynojvr: The receiving end needs to be able to *deserialise* it. So even if you used `writeReplace()` to change what was written to the stream, the object at the other end needs to be able to read the fields from the stream. In other words, your superclass on the client side would have to have a custom `readObject()` method that knew how to pick apart the fields.

Comment: @rynojvr: why do you have this 'atypical' arrangement?

Comment: I'm making a distributed processing mesh for a school project. The client is supposed to be able to create their own WorkUnit that they want the mesh to work on.

Comment: @rynojvr: If you have the class available on the server side (however you like to get it there), then it will deserialise okay.

Comment: @rynojvr: how does the server *execute* the work if it doesn't have the concrete implementation that *defines* what the work to do is?

Comment: The server sends the work out to other clients. They do the work. I guess I got away with it before because the Implementation was in the project, and so they had access to it to deserialize it. I was hoping it would be sufficient to subclass a common class.

Comment: @rynojvr: That's my point - all the nodes that need to do the work need to have a copy of the implementation class, because it not only contains the *data* to work on (its serialised fields), but it also contains *logic*: `return (input % 2 == 1) ? input : null;`

Comment: I see that now. But like I said, I was hoping it was enough for the implementation to subclass WorkUnit.

Comment: It should be worth noting that on top of all those parameters, the ObjectOutputStream also checks the class's package. I just ran into this same problem because the sent class was in package A.B.C, but on the receiving end I'd accidentally placed it in C.B.A.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem sometimes and I solved it by putting the class that's to be sent over the network in a package of its own (both on the sending end and the receiving end) and then import it into the class where its being sent or received. Note that the package structure should be the same on both ends.

Answer (score 0):

As a guess, you are running the sender and the receiver on different machines.  Did you check that they have the same version of this class on each field?

Comment: They're on the same machine now, but that's only for development purposes. The goal was to have someone write their own WorkUnit and then send it off to be worked on.

Answer (score 0):

Yea, I had the same problem. I have solved it by using the same serialized class on the same package. Put ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream function in the same package and execute output then input or call separately.