# Java adding a programmatically compiled class to the current Class's list of available references

Tags: java

As an extension of [Java ClassNotFoundException when reading object from a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479481/java-classnotfoundexception-when-reading-object-from-a-stream)

I have added the ability for the server to recieve the .java file, and it can compile it. However, I am still getting the same ClassNotFoundException. How can I make the server see and use the class it compiled to read the object from the objectInputStream?

Code to read and compile the .java on the serverSide:

```
    private void doNewWorkUnitDefinition(Object object) {
    NewWorkUnitDefinition newWorkUnitDefinition = (NewWorkUnitDefinition)object;
    byte[] bytes = newWorkUnitDefinition.getBytes();
    String name = newWorkUnitDefinition.getName();

    if (isClient) 
        client.gotNewWorkUnitDefinition(bytes, name);
    else {
        String executionPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        File file = new File(executionPath, name);
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fileOut.write(bytes);
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("Just wrote a file to: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

            JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
            compiler.run(System.in, System.out, System.err, file.getAbsolutePath());

            ClassLoader cl_old = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            ClassLoader cl_new = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { file
                    .getParentFile().toURI().toURL() }, cl_old);
            System.out.println("WorkUnitFile: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            Class compiledClass = cl_new.loadClass(file.getName()
                    .replace(".java", ""));
            this.

            sendConfirmDefinitionReceipt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page had exactly what I was looking for:

http://jimlife.wordpress.com/2007/12/19/java-adding-new-classpath-at-runtime/

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past is to load the classes by calling the defineClass method of the current class loader (using reflection)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/essence/files/Essence%20Java%20Config.%20Files/Essence%20JCF%201.02/

Comment: I can't see the source code. Could you possibly link or show it?

Comment: The source can be downloaded from that link but it can also be browsed http://essence.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/essence/trunk/essence-file/src/main/java/org/freshvanilla/compile/